# Null dependency in gradle? (workaround for lazy downloads?)

Tags: gradle

I would like to be able to write something like this:

```
dependencies {
    myConfig computeMyDependency()
}
```

and I want to be able to say "there is no dependency". Returning null or an empty map doesn't work. I suppose I can return `files('/dev/null')`, but that is weird, hacky and not portable. Is there some sort of null dependency constructor I can use?

Some background:

What I'm really trying to do is to defer dependency download to actual execution time. It appears that if a write a task, for example a copy task like so:

```
task copyMyDependencyFile(type: Copy) {
    from { configurations.myConfig
               .grep { it.name.endsWith("zip") }
               .collect() { zipTree it }
         }
    into targetDir
}
```

Then running `./gradlew tasks` will actually execute the `from` closure, which makes me very sad. (Using Gradle 2.4)

Comment: returning `files('.')` also "works" (i.e. `./gradlew tasks` doesn't fail), and is hopefully more portable, but it would be nicer if there was a proper "null" dependency.

Comment: Apparently, `./gradlew tasks` will resolve task inputs and outputs in order to display task dependencies - https://discuss.gradle.org/t/lazy-dependency-evaluation-how/11473/2

Comment: Can you please share a runnable example?

Comment: just add a definition for `computeMyDependeny()` which returns a string to an artifact that doesn't exist. My point here is that this shouldn't prevent `gradle tasks` from workiing.

Comment: Please, se my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround might be also:

```
task copyMyDependencyFile << {
   copy {
      from { 
         configurations.
         compile.
         grep { it.name.endsWith("jar") }.
         collect { zipTree it }
      }
      into targetDir
   }
}
```

It should be portable.

Not sure but maybe `from` and `into` maybe configured in `doLast` closure of task with type `Copy`:

```
task copyMyDependencyFile(type: Copy) {
   doLast {
      from { 
         configurations.
         compile.
         grep { it.name.endsWith("jar") }.
         collect { zipTree it }
       }
       into targetDir
    }
}
```

Please try the latter yourself.

Comment: I think that will obscure the inputs and outputs of the task. According to the gradle forum folks, it's exactly those inputs and outputs that cause the problem, because `gradle tasks` tries to also show task dependencies. I guess this whole thing shows the danger of too much abstraction. Artifact and file dependencies add no task dependency info and therefore shouldn't get resolved, but since they just use the high level dependency abstraction, it happens anyways...

Comment: In this case yes, inputs and outputs will not work as expected.